# Sending secure data from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, security

I have a quiz system built in HTML/CSS/JS and I recently added to it php to add the score gained via JS into my database. I'm using ajax to send the score and receive it in PHP. The problem is, anyone is able to send the same request via console so this method isn't secure at all. Please suggest me a way to improve security of this code so no one can send fake score requests to my database.

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
function addScore(gType, amount) { 
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost/TM/backend/score.backend.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('score request sent: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('score=' + amount + '&gType=' + gType);
}
```

PHP:

```php
    $score = $_POST["score"];
    $type = $_POST["gType"];
    echo $score;
    echo $type;

    //log in
    session_start();    
    include_once "../db/config.php";
    
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION["email"]);
    if ($type == "allemand") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` set scoreAllemand=scoreAllemand+? WHERE email=?;";
    } else if ($type == "drapeaux") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` set scoreDrapeaux=scoreDrapeaux+? WHERE email=?;";
    } else if ($type == "carte") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` set scoreCarte=scoreCarte+? WHERE email=?;";
    } else if ($type == "italien") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` set scoreItalien=scoreItalien+? WHERE email=?;";
    } else if ($type == "anglais") {
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` set scoreAnglais=scoreAnglais+? WHERE email=?;";
    }
    
    // execute without parameters
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    
    // security 
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "SQL ERROR";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $score, $email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
```

Comment: Do not mix `mysqli_real_escape_string()` with prepared statements.  Just feed the string as a bound parameter to the prepared statement.  `elseif` is one word in php.  Write `session_start();` before any other line of code (as a matter of good practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> anyone is able to send the same request via console so this method
> isn't secure at all

...the same would be true if you used a normal postback. Someone could view the format of the request and see what is being sent, and then fake a similar request (either using the browser console, or a separate tool such as PostMan or their own bespoke program).

So AJAX is not the issue here, the issue is that you should never trust anything sent from the client to the server, because you can never be 100% certain how it was sent.

If you don't want it to be possible for anyone to tamper with the score, you need to re-design it so that the front-end submits only the user's answers, and then PHP will need to check them and calculate the score.

---

P.S. As an aside, you need to remove `mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` (as it is likely to fail and is also redundant because you're executing the query with parameters later) and also remove all calls to `mysqli_real_escape_string()` - since you're using parameters, you don't need it (and it could actually actively harm the data in some cases).

It's also good practice, if you need it, to write `session_start();` before any other line of code, so that you know it will always be ready before you need to use any Session variables.

Comment: @mickmackusa Done. I left out the `elseif` remark since `else if` is only an issue in specific circumstances (which don't apply here) - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php